# infinite recursion options(expressions=) at R startup and updating packages

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

i have a problem i can't find a solution to. On startup R says:
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

then, R works up until i try to update packages: "digest 0.6.16", "stringi 1.2.4", "tinytex 0.7"

this gives the error again: 
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Execution halted
In R CMD INSTALL

The same when i try to build the website through blogdown.

i run R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray" on R studio Version 1.1.456

I tried the following: 
modifying options(expression= 500000) (and other values)
i tried reinstalling R and R studio

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you loading a previously saved workspace on startup? If so, does the error still show up after deleting the file `.RData`?

Comment: I don't load any workspace on startup, i tried deleting the .RData file and restart, but the error is still present... Also tried cleaning workspace with the option hidden object checked, restarted, and still the same error on startup...

Comment: What is in your startup profile file (e.g. `.Rprofile`)?

Comment: Sorry for cross-posting without warning. It was the .Rprofile indeed. I completely forgotten that i used a formula that supposedly automatically set my name as author for posts in blogdown that i found in some blog that now i really don't remember. Anyhow, i deleted it and now the issue is solved. Thanks for you time.